# I think this question was mistakenly closed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I'm wondering if this is a case of herd mentality... The question [*Getting started on a TFS project, bin and obj folders are tracked - now what?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859660/getting-started-on-a-tfs-project-bin-and-obj-folders-are-tracked-now-what) was closed as Not Constructive. Originally the question is a little waffly, but the TL;DR is very specific.

Not only is it constructive and very answerable, the answer is useful in other situations when you have a read-only file that is interfering with the build process.

I want to tender an answer for this, but cannot. Could we please get it reopened?

As an aside, what are the chances of a question making it through the close review queue once it has achieved its first one or two votes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question is rather long winded for what is really an easy question:

> In TFS, the `bin` and `obj` folders are listed as locked, and it throws a monkey wrench into the build process. How do I fix this?

Certainly a constructive question (although the use of the phrase `best approach` probably triggered the close crowd).

I re-opened it. I will edit it.

You have the reputation to edit this post.  I think that if you had followed your instincts and edited the post, the community *may* have responded by re-opening it.

The best approach is to do the following:

- Edit the post
- Vote to re-open it.
- If a few hours goes by and there aren't any other re-open votes, then:
- flag it for re-opening with your reasons

Answer (score 6):

There is a single sentence in that question which stands out above all else:

> Anyone have any suggestions?

Another piece that stands out:

> I'm really not sure what the best approach is

This is not the place to ask for suggestions. Using key-phrases like "suggestions" and "best approach" are *extremely* subjective sounding and yes, will get the question closed. As it stands now, the question appears to be very subjective, but sitting on the border-line. Try rephrasing it so it doesn't use these subjective phrases. The actual question appears valid.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but it's unfortunate when a valid question is closed just because it isn't phrased *just so*. The point is more important than the wording and wording can be easily fixed with an edit by a more experienced user (which George just demonstrated).

Comment: @AnnaLear makes a good point. This is why it's important to try to edit a question before closing it. An edited question not only exposes it's hidden value, but also it can help expose inherent flaws. This helps us know that we're closing appropriately. I will add this though: Questions tend to get better answers when those keywords aren't present, constructive or not... +1